# Vertically align text when using inline-block

Tags: html, vertical-alignment, css

I have been searching for an answer for this for days now and no solution seems to be the correct one for my needs. Please help!

I have two divs for which I want to fill 100% width of the browser, and have more of these which will stack to fill the height. **I want the text in each of these** (which is being generated from javascript  ) **to be vertically aligned.**

I have also tried using display:table-cell and it works great in all ways, however I do not have the ability to set the cell width as a fixed %, and I need to add html markup which seems to limit me in using certain media queries later on.

**How can I vertically align text using inline-block?**

Im having trouble making a fiddle but this is close: http://jsfiddle.net/z4bj14op/

Here is my CSS

```
html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        font-family: helvetica;
    }
    #status {
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 0;
    }
    #line0, #status0 {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
        vertical-align: middle; 
        height: 10%;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    #line0 {
        background-color: #B36305;
        color: white;
    }
    #status0 {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }
```

And the HTML

```
<div id ="status">
    <div id="line0"></div>  
    <div id="status0"></div>        
</div>
```

Comment: Show your markup too and if possible make a fiddle which may help us

Answer (score 0):

There is an article from Steven Bradley **6 Methods For Vertical Centering With CSS**: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Which solution would be the best depends on your requirements. I think the *Absolute Positioning and Negative Margin* way could be the solution you need, as your container have a defined height.

---

When using `display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle` the element is only vertically centered to the other inline-elements of the current row.

Comment: Thanks so much, that looks promising. Following that example, I would need to make the parent relatively positioned and the child absolutely positioned. How does this work when I am using inline-block to position my elements? Should I create nested divs, and if so, where should they go?

Comment: I guess you need a wrapper `div` then, which is `position:absolute;top:50%;height:10%;margin-top:-5%` which contains all the `display:inline-block` elements

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want ?

[JSfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Souka159/qevwLsco/)

If you want both of the divs to be 100% in their width that impossible ! otherwise the rest of the div will hidden by the other one

clarify more what's needed ..

```
<div id ="status">
<div id="line0"><h2>Bakerloo</h2></div> 
<div id="status0"><h2>Good Service</h2></div>
</div>
```

css code:

```
#line0{
background:pink;
width:50%;
display: inline-block;
}
```

`#status0{
    background:red;
    width:49%;
    display: inline-block;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using display: inline-block? must you use this way? try to put float: left instead display: inline-block inside block #line0,#status0 and after you can work with text-something else

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this

```
#line0{
    background:pink;
    width:50%;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;/*added*/
}
#status0{    
    background:red;
    width:50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/qevwLsco/1/)**